# Ascending/descending single climbing rope without any other gear

Tags: climbing

I am interested in emergency ascending/descending a climbing rope, where there is no other gear and time is of the essence.

Basically, I wonder if anyone has had success with a swiss seat from a bight or at the end of a rope, then a Blake Hitch.